# remove gap between div?

Tags: html, css

I have a question, I tried to search on google but unluckily I didn't find any answer...

So i want to remove gap between DIVs.
I have a small PHP application which shows users images in a div with some other info, DIV width is 250px and DIV height is auto because I don't know the length of content and I also didn't know the number of the DIV because i fetch data from MYSQL.

Here is a screen-shoot of my web page:
[image: Here is a screen-shoot of my web page]

And my code is:

```
<style>
#det
{
width:250;
height:auto;
max-height:400px;
border-bottom:3px solid darkred;
background-color:white;
float:left;

padding:0px;
margin:0 auto;
border-radius:5px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id='det'>
<img src='$user_image'><p>some text</p>
</div>
```

I want to remove gap between DIV and show it how a magazine-style look like. Example: [masonry.desandro.com](http://masonry.desandro.com). Currently i used `float:left` but it's not working properly and maybe because I didn't set height. Is there anyway to solve this without set div height?

Thanks

Comment: where is the gap? I can't see any gap. Explain in detail and show the image how to want to make your front end look like

Comment: ID should be unique (use class instead), and i think that you will need something like this: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: yes You are right (@nevermind) but i can not use different id's becuse i fetch data from mysql

Comment: Or, since you use php in backend, you can create 'rows' with 3 pictures per row (for example). in that case you can solve this with css only....

Comment: actually i can't use rows is there any other way using javascript?

Comment: Why you can't? You control output, right? Hint: use modulo operator for creating.... P.S. In any case - some gap will be there, so... i guess only masonry-like javascript will help in this case.

Comment: Please reproduce the above in jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Use flex fluid layout for showing variable height elements properly.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  width: 179px;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w4pfxk2x/

Answer (score 0):

You should use `display:inline-block;` instead of `float:left;` and your problem will be fixed.

```
.det{
width:250;
height:auto;
max-height:400px;
border-bottom:3px solid darkred;
background-color:white;
display:inline-block;
padding:0px;
margin:0 auto;
border-radius:5px;
vertical-align:top
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/haqkxkmb/

Comment: it solve my 50% problem but gap is still there..
i need something like this
masonry.desandro.com

Comment: @Joe, download that script, and use it, then... As far as i know, that's the only solution (or to make script like that, which is not so easy).

Comment: It is impossible to do it with only style so you will need to download and use the ready script, I'm sorry man I didn't understand you at the beginning.