# How to fit contents perfectly under the flex property?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, gallery

I have 2 containers that called `.grid.left` and `.grid.right`. Each `.grids`, especially `.grid.left` has some images dynamical ways and those`.grids` are wrapped by another div called `.gallery`.

The problem is when I give margin each of the image boxes, the browser makes a little gaps inside of the `.gallery` like this:

[image]

My expectation is to get rid of that gaps from my `.gallery` and to make the images fit completely no matter how much I set the `margins` on the images.

I intended to give the `margins` for the gallery looking better. I want to remain those margins and expand the `.grid.right`'s image only to fit between the image and the `.outer` div.

Are there any proper ways to resolve this problem?

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/sniffingdoggo/pen/EzRYqN)

Snippets:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div,
section {
  position: relative;
}

.gallery {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.article {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.grid {
  height: 100%;
}

.left {
  width: 60%;
}

.inset-contents {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}

.top {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  background-image: url('https://imgur.com/3ozQvk9.jpg');
  padding-bottom: 50%;
}

.bottom {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}

.inner-contents {
  width: 50%;
}

.first {
  background-image: url('https://imgur.com/tOMRVDi.jpg');
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  margin-right: .5rem;
}

.second {
  background-image: url('https://imgur.com/4oewNdx.jpg');
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  margin-left: .5rem;
}

.right {
  width: 40%;
  background-image: url('https://imgur.com/7gB1jHR.jpg');
  padding-bottom: 60%;
  align-content: stretch;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.img {
  display: block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="article">
    <div class="grid left">
      <a class="inset-contents top img"></a>
      <div class="inset-contents bottom">
        <a class="inner-contents first img"></a>
        <a class="inner-contents second img"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="grid right img"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the reason why you're getting gap in your `.gallery` is because you're giving each child of your `.gallery` a `margin`

Comment: @indefinite I intended to give the margins for looking better. I want to remain those and expanded the `.grid.right` image only to fit the gallery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is how you are managing the height of the `right` element in your image gallery:

- omit setting `height: 100%` (due to `grid` class) and the `padding-bottom` - you can override this by adding `height: auto` to the `right` element,
- remove `align-items: center` from the `article` element and allow the default `align-items: stretch` to take over - this will *stretch* and match the height of the `right` element to the `left`.

See demo below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div,
section {
  position: relative;
}

.gallery {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.article {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  /*align-items: center;*/
}

.grid {
  height: 100%;
}

.left {
  width: 60%;
}

.inset-contents {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}

.top {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  background-image: url('https://imgur.com/3ozQvk9.jpg');
  padding-bottom: 50%;
}

.bottom {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}

.inner-contents {
  width: 50%;
}

.first {
  background-image: url('https://imgur.com/tOMRVDi.jpg');
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  margin-right: .5rem;
}

.second {
  background-image: url('https://imgur.com/4oewNdx.jpg');
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  margin-left: .5rem;
}

.right {
  width: 40%;
  background-image: url('https://imgur.com/7gB1jHR.jpg');
  /*padding-bottom: 60%;
  align-content: stretch; */
  margin-left: 1rem;
  height: auto; /* added */
}

.img {
  display: block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="article">
    <div class="grid left">
      <a class="inset-contents top img"></a>
      <div class="inset-contents bottom">
        <a class="inner-contents first img"></a>
        <a class="inner-contents second img"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="grid right img"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've already found an another solution, but I think your way is better than mine. Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377072/remove-gap-between-div) article, I needed to add `flex-shrink: 0;` in `.right` like this:

```css
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  div, section {
    position: relative;
  }
  .gallery {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .article {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .grid {
    height: 100%;
  }
  .left {
    width: 60%;
  }
  .inset-contents {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
  }
  .top {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    background-image: url('https://imgur.com/3ozQvk9.jpg');
    padding-bottom: 50%;
  }
  .bottom {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
  }
  .inner-contents {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .first {
    background-image: url('https://imgur.com/tOMRVDi.jpg');
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    margin-right: .5rem;
  }
  .second {
    background-image: url('https://imgur.com/4oewNdx.jpg');
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    margin-left: .5rem;
  }
  .right {
    width: 40%;
    background-image: url('https://imgur.com/7gB1jHR.jpg');
    padding-bottom: 60%;
    align-content: stretch;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    flex-shrink: 0;
  }
  .img {
    display: block;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
  }
```

```html
    <div class="gallery">
      <div class="article">
        <div class="grid left">
          <a class="inset-contents top img"></a>
          <div class="inset-contents bottom">
            <a class="inner-contents first img"></a>
            <a class="inner-contents second img"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="grid right img"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

hello If I'm correct you just want to get rid of the gap and wants to expand the images.
You may check this one.

```css
          * {
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 0 auto;
          }
          div, section {
            position: relative;
          }
          .gallery {
            width: 1200px;
            height: 100%;
            border: 1px solid black;
            box-sizing: border-box;
          }
          .article {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: row;
            align-items: center;
          }
          .grid {
            height: 100%;
          }
          .left {
            width: 60%;
          }
          .inset-contents {
            width: 100%;
            height: 50%;
          }
          .top {
        
            background-image: url('https://imgur.com/3ozQvk9.jpg');
            padding-bottom: 50%;
          }
          .bottom {
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: row;
          }
          .inner-contents {
            width: 50%;
          }
          .first {
            background-image: url('https://imgur.com/tOMRVDi.jpg');
            padding-bottom: 50%;
          
          }
          .second {
            background-image: url('https://imgur.com/4oewNdx.jpg');
            padding-bottom: 50%;
      
          }
          .right {
            width: 40%;
            background-image: url('https://imgur.com/7gB1jHR.jpg');
            padding-bottom: 60%;
            align-content: stretch;

          }
          .img {
            display: block;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center center;
          }
```

```html
        <div class="gallery">
          <div class="article">
            <div class="grid left">
              <a class="inset-contents top img"></a>
              <div class="inset-contents bottom">
                <a class="inner-contents first img"></a>
                <a class="inner-contents second img"></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="grid right img"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

You just need to remove all margin that you put in the `.gallery` child.

Comment: I need the rest of margins for the images looking better. What I wanted was expanded the `.grid.right`'s image vertically.